# Retrieve embedded image from ViewModel in xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, embedded-resource

I have a project that has a sequence of views that are used for an on boarding sequence/tutorial for the app. I prefer to embed the resources in the main project (they are not different for each platform). Also, some of the resources are GIFs while others are SVG and a couple of PNG's.

How do I reference embedded images from the ViewModel? I looked at the images sample on MSFT docs, but it doesn't really solve the problem for me. Also, I have to either use ffImageLoading (or Skia) to render my SVGs.

I am sure others have dealt with this issue - so looking for lessons learned. My GIF's are a little large - so perf is a big consideration. I have the project working but perf is very poor and maintaining iOS and Android versions of the same assets is a waste.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is explicitly addressed in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows#loading-files-embedded-as-resources) and in hundreds of existing questions.  It's a basic C# issue, not anything specific to Xamarin

Comment: Please give more detail. StackOverflow is designed for specific questions, usually showing code, such that concrete answers can be given. "perf is very poor": What does your XAML and cs look like now? How big are the images visually on screen? Dimensions of image files in pixels? Loading one image, or a collection of images? "very poor": How long does it take, to do what action, measured on what physical device? Re large GIFs: Are they large because they will be large on screen? Maybe have small thumbnail files, then click to load large one?

Comment: Re images sample in docs - is that [Images in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows)? Which section of that doc seems like it *should* be able to handle your situation (but doesn't), and what exactly about the solution given in doc falls short of your needs? Is this more a *display performance* issue, or a *loading technique* (asset management) issue? or both?

Comment: Another way to think about this:  Have you done native development (either via Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android, or using native tools provided by Apple or Google) on one of the platforms? If so, how would you have solved this natively? I'm not sure if what you are grappling with is specific to Xamarin.Forms/cross-platform development, or is more about how to work with images in mobile apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for the comments. What I was forgetting is that I just needed to bind to the resource ID of the embedded image - and simply set that value in my viewmodel. In short, my question was poorly written and I was not thinking about it.